# Change disk from NTFS/exFAT/HPFS to LinuxLVM (0x82) without formating

Tags: partitioning

To make it short: I have a 1TB external hard drive where I store my DejaDup backups and now I also want to store Timeshift backups there. Problem is this 1TB hard drive is NTFS/exFAT/HPFS and Timeshift requires a Linux format hard drive to store backups on. In the "Disks" I can "edit partition" and switch to LinuxLVM (0x82), what Timeshift wants, but I am afraid to do that because I may lose all of the files on that hard drive. Will I? Is this going to delete all of the files and reformat? Or break the hard drive?

Comment: what's Timeshift?

Comment: Timeshift is a neat app that creates snapshots of your entire system (for backup). https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot properly change filesystem types without formatting.  Filesystem types cannot be switched readily like that.  This applies for *every* operating system - Windows, Linux, and MacOS - and is not a limitation specific to one OS or file system type.

If you want to store Timeshift backups on the disk, you need to back up the data you don't want to lose either to your computer or to a different disk, format the drive to be LinuxLVM, and then copy your files back.  If this is your OS disk, then you'll have to format then reinstall.

There's no other way around reformatting the partition unfortunately, as you can't switch between filesystem types without that reformat step.  (NTFS, exFAT, HPFS, LVM, etc. don't speak the same 'language' when it comes to how partitions and the filesystems work at the raw byte level in terms of what is stored where for disk information, file allocation tables/journals, etc.; this is why the reformat step is necessary to change the file system types)

Comment: thank you. that's what I thought but wasn't sure.